# Data-Slide-to bootstrap binding Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

Is it posibble to bind index property of *ngFor directive of Angular to some attribute that isnt part of native html?

```
<ol class="carousel-indicator">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{i}}" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Yes you can , what problem are you facing exactly

Answer (score 21):

```
Please edit to:
```

```
<li *ngFor="let banner of banners,let i = index" data-target="#carousel" class="{{ (i == 0) ? 'active' : '' }}" attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}"></li>
```

*** edit: attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}" => Success**

Comment: attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}" does the job on Angular 7 as well.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

data-slide-to  ----->  [attr.data-slide-to]

Comment: This is working for custom attribute, not only for bootstrap data-slide-to. I'm using angular 5

Comment: awesome, still the way to go with angular6

Answer (score 1):

use `v-bind:data-slide-to="index"`

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" 
     v-for="(image, index) in images" v-bind:key="index"
     v-bind:data-slide-to="index"
    :class="{'active' : index===0}"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<ol class="carousel-indicator">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" [data-slide-to]="i" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index></li>
</ol>
```

`data-slide-to="i"` -> `[data-slide-to]="i"`